# Password validation in a separate constant file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use a Regular expression for password validation with at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character. I want to define it in a separate constant file and want to access it in my main file.

## code snippet-

```
[self.txtf_createpassword addRegx:REGEX_PASSWORD withMsg:@"validation error message"];
```

In my constant file, I am not getting how to set up my regex.

regex in my constant file -

```
   #define REGEX_PASSWORD @"[A-Za-z0-9!@#$%"@"^&*]{8,16}"
```

// how to set up the expression here

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
static NSString*constantPsss = @"anything";
```

Comment: I want to access it through my constant file, but I am not getting how to set up my regex in my constant file

Comment: first constants file is a .h file only ,second declare it like this in the .h file then import it or use .pch for general access anywhere

Comment: But How to set up my regex expression as per my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

In your .h constants file (let say your file is called "constants.h")  write this  :

```
#define REGEX_PASSWORD @"xxxxxxx"
```

Then in your file where you want to use it, write this :

```
#import "constants.h"
```

Then you will be able to call your code :

```
[self.txtf_createpassword addRegx:REGEX_PASSWORD withMsg:@"validation error message"];
```